# Dictionaries with a tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to re-create the below through code:

```
publications = {"publicationId": "gid://shopify/Publication/17878646899"}, {
                "publicationId": "gid://shopify/Publication/18034294899"}
```

Something like this:

```
shopify_channel_names = "17878646899;18034294899"
shopify_channel_names_split = shopify_channel_names.split(';')
for count, shopify_channel in enumerate(shopify_channel_names_split):
    print shopify_channel
    got_publication = {"publicationId": "gid://shopify/Publication/" + shopify_channel}
```

When I have the publication I don't know how to create the publications, everything I can do it with index ids, but I don't need that.

Comment: it looks like you try to create json array. is that the case (i.e. ultimate goal)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
shopify_channel_names = "17878646899;18034294899"
publications = tuple({"publicationId": "gid://shopify/Publication/{}".format(pub_id)} 
                      for pub_id in shopify_channel_names.split(';'))
print publications
```

output

```
({'publicationId': 'gid://shopify/Publication/17878646899'}, {'publicationId': 'gid://shopify/Publication/18034294899'})
```